# How to delete a dynamic array of objects with pointers to other objects (C++)

Tags: c++, dynamic, hash, garbage

Long story short, I have to code a hashtable using linear hashing in C++ for university. The hashtable works, but the ressources are not being freed which is an issue, especially that the unit test tests the table with 100k+ values and the garbage left behind is huge.
Basically when I'm creating the new hashtable I am doing the following:

```
hashTable = new Bucket[this->tableSize];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            hashTable[i] = * new Bucket();
        }
```

Each Bucket can contain a pointer to another overflow bucket, which may or may not be set.

```
    class Bucket {
    private:
        size_t bucketSize;                                                                   
        size_t elementsInBucket;                                                              
        E v[N];   // int v[N];                                                              
        bool hasOverflow;                                                                     
        Bucket * nextBucket = nullptr;
```

My question is, how can I delete the whole hashtable including the buckets with their potential overflow buckets as the following only frees half of the occupied memory.

```
delete[] hashTable;
hashTable = nullptr;
```

Thanks!

Comment: A `Bucket` is essentially just a node of a linked list. So what's the usual way to delete a linked list?

Comment: I don't see a destructor for `Bucket`.

Comment: `virtual ~Bucket() {
                delete nextBucket;
            }` If I code the destructor, the program breaks and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when expanding the array.

Comment: @cookiemonster The destructor is telling you there is a problem further upstream.  So you need to leave the destructor in the code and fix the actual problem (the problem is not the destructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, the following line of code is a memory leak:

```
hashTable[i] = * new Bucket();
```

What you are doing here is allocating a new Bucket object on the heap, then immediately copying it by value into your array. The pointer you created with new falls out of scope, and the original Bucket on the heap is leaked. What you have remaining is a *copy* of what you just allocated in the heap and leaked.

Instead, you should store the pointers in your array as such:

```
hashTable = new *Bucket[this->tableSize];
for (size_t i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
    hashTable[i] = new Bucket();
}
```

and delete it as such:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
    delete hashTable[i];
    hashTable[i] = nullptr;
}
delete[] hashTable;
hashTable = nullptr;
```

You should also make sure your destructor deletes the member pointer so that when you call delete on each Bucket pointer the nested memory is deallocated:

```
~Bucket() { 
    delete nextBucket;
    nextBucket = nullptr; 
}
```

Last, you will need to change any code that does this:

```
hashTable[i].something
```

to this:

```
hashTable[i]->something
```

This seems to me to be the proper way to handle dynamic arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out tomorrow because it's kinda late over here :D

Answer (score 3):

You are immediately leaking one `Bucket` on this line:

```
hashTable[i] = * new Bucket();
```

What this does is:

1. Allocate a new `Bucket` and return a pointer to it
2. Dereference the returned pointer and pass a reference to your new `Bucket` to `Bucket::operator=`
3. Copy the empty `Bucket` into the already existing object `hashTable[i]`
4. Discard the pointer to your newly allocated `Bucket`, thus leaking it

`hashTable` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `tableSize` `Bucket`s.  Those objects already exist, so you don't need to allocate new ones in your loop.

Additionally, you've not shown a destructor for `Bucket`, or shown how you allocate `Bucket::nextBucket`.  I'm assuming each `Bucket` should own its `nextBucket`, so you should have a destructor that does something like

```
Bucket::~Bucket()
{
    delete nextBucket;
}
```

Comment: The destructor is pretty much like the one you have written. In addition to that i am also assigning nextBucket to nullptr. As for the allocation of nextBucket, a method add(const E& e) is called for adding the object to the bucket. If the current bucket is full, a new bucket is created an the object gets added in that bucket. The problem is that when using such a destructor I get a EXC_BAD+ACCESS

Comment: Something's probably wrong in your `add` method then.  Something causing a double-free or use-after-free most likely.

Comment: The error pops up when checking if the current bucket has other overflow buckets. But thanks! I will look it up in the morning.